# Implementing timed events in C

Tags: c, linux, timer, pthreads, intervals

I am writing a simple application to check some records in an interval on Linux (x86/x86_64)
Each record has its own checking interval which can be between 5 and 300 seconds.
This is the record structure:

```
...
typedef struct record_t {
    char name[256];
    time_t last_check;
    unsigned int interval;
    unsigned long amount;
    struct record_t *next;
} struct_t;
...
```

and the thread that checks records:

```
...
/* records is a pointer to the first record in the linked list */
while(1) {
    for (current_record = records;
         current_record != NULL;
         current_record = current_record->next)
         {
            if(current_record->last_check + current_record->interval < time(0))
                update_record(current_record);
         }
    sleep(1);
}
...
```

The record list's length can be vary greatly (e.g. from 2 to 100 000)
and this will get slower and slower with each element pushed in the list...
Is there a way to optimize it or have a trigger with each record
so instead of checking everything with a loop,
a callback is invoked when the interval passes?
More or less, I'm looking for something like setInterval() from JavaScript.

Thanks for everything

Answer (score 2, accepted):

implement a timer wheel. make an array of 301 pointers.
instead of queuing the records just like that, queue them according to the time-out.
have

```
while(1) {
    sleep (1);
    currIndx = (currIndx + 1) % 301;

    /* process the link list starting at that variable. */
    procQ = timerWheel[currIndx];

    /* re queue if necessay */

}
```

and the queuing code:

```
queIndx = (currIndx + timeout) % 301;
procQ = timerWheel[queIndx];
/* add at the head of link list */
```